# Conflict with jQuery On Function.PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am getting an issue when adding the jQuery in `fucntions.php`. When adding it, some stuff stop working like `ACF Datepicker`, `Wordpress Admin with JS dropdown` also stop working IDK what happen but the issue when adding the jquery everything on related to js is suddenly stop working..

please help me.

```
<?php
function Load_CSS() {
    wp_register_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array (), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('main');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Lora&family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap',array(), null );                                
    wp_register_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'),'1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('script');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.1/css/all.css',array(), null );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','Load_CSS');

// Load External JS & CSS

wp_register_script('x', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('x'); <-- This is the jQuery im talking about.

wp_register_script( 'Slick', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('Slick');
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, jquery base library is already added to WordPress, so I don't think you have to add it again.

Comment: so maybe that is the problem? then bro how to add it on functions.php i added it because i want it to work on slick slider

Comment: I think the slider will work without adding the jQuery base library.

Comment: Is not working.. i commented out. but is not working. do i need to change the version?

Comment: if your slick slider working with new version then yes for-sure but as you said that other things stopped working so check and find out the appropriate version which support both.

Comment: Slick is working with all version of jquery. that was im testing last night

Comment: Bro its work when putting it on footer.php but when placing it on functions.php error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your website is probably loading multiple versions of jquery beacuse you have just registered a new one with a different name. Ideally you should deregister the default one and register a new one:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js", false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```